# Vuetify VDataTable an VDataTableServer when an item expanded other items must be collapsed

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

I'm trying to collapse other rows to show fetched data on last expanded row and i didnt figure it out how to do that. I tried isExpanded and toggleExpand props but still doesn't work properly.

in expandeFn function i fetch users profile data but @update:expanded returns me an array of expanded items. I want to get last expanded users data or all expanded areas show same profile or returns me an error.

```
<VDataTableServer
        :items="users"
        item-value="_id"
        :headers="headers"
        :loading="loading.table"
        no-data-text="Nothing found"
        show-expand
        @update:expanded="expandeFn"
      >
        <template #item.username="{ item }">
          <div class="d-flex align-center">
            <div
              class="d-flex flex-column"
            >
              <h6 class="text-body-1 font-weight-medium">
                {{
                  item.raw.username
                }}
              </h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>

        <template #expanded-row="{ columns }">
          <tr :colspan="columns.length">
            <td :colspan="columns.length">
              <VRow style="padding-top: 1rem; padding-bottom: 1rem">
                <VCol
                  v-for="category in categories"
                  :key="category"
                  cols="12"
                  lg="4"
                >
                  <VCard
                    :title="category?.interestName"
                    style="background-color: #020b15; border-radius: 1rem"
                  >
                    <template #append>
                      <div v-if="category" class="d-flex gap-1 flex-wrap">
                        {{ category?.count ? category?.count : 0 }}
                      </div>
                    </template>
                  </VCard>
                </VCol>
              </VRow>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </VDataTableServer>
```

i need to collapse all other rows but not last one clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an array to bind to the [`expanded`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-expanded) prop. Now you can use [`update:expanded`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#events-update:expanded) to remove all entries of previously expanded rows from the array:

```html
<v-data-table-server
    :expanded="expanded"
    @update:expanded="newExpanded => expanded = newExpanded.slice(-1)"
  ...
```

Now all but the last expanded row will be collapsed. If necessary, you can build more complex expand/collapse logic from this.

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqtll1v2jAUhv/KUaSprVTCZ2iJaLWp7daum7SL3UylFyYxENXEke3AOsR/n00+bWIG0rio4nPO6zzn9TH0ZeNwFrQ/JYm7SrHjO2OBlwlBAt9OYoDxqhUigVoCTQlWAQAf/05QHOLwZuIUjxMny31ME1mO6yUxXj/kK7i5hSIDN1DLuJxEAT5vdS+KnfwFRiFmXO4QYs4xE49ZoCyIJGgtXSZUvLVCJMXq7WiJiwRf0HUre78K7PqTHRb9wqrFCRW+oEme2rUvKCVTxGAma8p4PdMSkSD4NmtF2QQ/1d9x26woN60yBUNbM70BqrCtxehatrWBgJJ0GfPLXbuwnTjV9qLYNluF4MtiLvVSmMtcguO5WEjVd8owRPGMAprSVMBms9vRVcbBdivJwhp4ubVBrFqq5kSGtLxc8oBFSeafbIUyASGeoZTIF2YbKvX5RbECYFikLK7WO93OAh9eXi+rsD4dMlmloC5Xn905+HB2n2ngvNvpzEE+rqJ4fnFW21V9EInmsazmAjFhJrnsQfXqwwwRjo3sG36XQuWhrttqq00JdIcIZRHmZ5e5NCgCVslnJPkVdK6YIWEvvkNsyrXyQEXsgh+MChzFmiTJYnbRE6NS8aFSRDJgLy/LqsnJr6euaTjtf5yzMl5ZxOgfHMMvOk/3D7Bw2IeuNzJy0ksfhm5nTyI986E3MOK5MT4M9iTKAfmGQ0PQiP4UYAgYRkvg0o91FCzs/L3+VRP/yMa/V17j7/8n/oeAoIgdYB72mpi7dtNNshJ6X5JB610eA32XJgF6M65snbrf8Zqo+67paA49PNnp65Ohv8ivLsymclbCA+De8DS7B+aVKMn7rpnKZ0R/wzHoXzEh7zDFKD5AftVoeccGPrJezn1JBq5Hj+H+RgmJEpocoB41jnfHNcMFtX7udepGZn2bY5gfaYzfA7qc2qEHHZMin24L9LV1uoeueWgZ9kAPH8N9T+P0wHf3wGs0uufZ5sPTv8u0K9k82L3TzX6OxLP8ObZSe91Gp3vW6zg0/SypzTPImO13sfox3WYPWVIuxu3ynzRne+n03YHbHTnqwXOvnNe/sVAdNw==)

Comment: when i add v-model:expanded="expanded" prop to v-data-table-server expandable area doesn't work properly.

Comment: Why, what happens?

Comment: here its example can you tell me what is wrong? [playground](https://shorturl.at/gpxTV)

Comment: The `expanded` array isn't reactive, it should be `const expanded : Ref<string[]> = ref([])`

Comment: thanks a lot for your patience and response.